# I am trying to use Verilog::Netlist module in my PERL script. This module has a shared lib auto/Verilog/Preproc/Preproc.so

Tags: perl, unix, environment-variables, shared-libraries, verilog

I am trying to use 'Verilog::Netlist' module in my PERL script, which contains a  lib auto/Verilog/Preproc/Preproc.so. 
This lib requires libstdc++.so.6 lib to be dynamically loaded.
How can I specify the path of the libstdc++.so.6?

Answer (score 0):

Run you Perl script like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/shared/libdir perl scriptname.pl
```

Try "man ld.so" for more information.

By the way, Unixes differ significantly in their implementation of shared libraries.  It never hurts to mention your operating system, when you ask something about shared libs.